# Drawing a rectangle in AS3, the border is partially off-screen

Tags: actionscript-3

I am drawing a rectangle at 0,0 with a line-style-thickness of 4px. It has height 100% and width 50%. The right-hand edge has a border 4px wide, but all 3 other sides are only 2px, suggesting the mid-point of the edge is classed as the border. Why isn't the edge drawn 'inside' the rectangle?

Comment: Is your rectangle on rounded pixels? Is the width a rounded value? FYI the line is drawn from the center of the edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because to draw a line, you only specify two points: A beginning, and an end. The line will be centered between them, making the left and right sides "stand out".

If you want to have a rectangle with a frame inside of the specified coordinates, consider creating a filled shape out of two Rectangles (the inner one will be subtracted from the outer one), without a lineStyle.

```
var sprite : Sprite = new Sprite( );
var g : Graphics = sprite.graphics;
g.lineStyle( null );
g.beginFill( 0, 1 );
g.drawRect( 0, 0, 200, 100 );
g.drawRect( 2, 2, 194, 96 );
g.endFill( );
addChild (sprite);
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a performance hit though, since 99%+ of pixels are in both?

Comment: The pixels won't be drawn until you've specified all the vectors.  So no, there shouldn't be.